# Distributing balls into distinct boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

So basically my question is this:

I have $30$ non distinct balls that I want to put inside $4$ distinct boxes. For every $1\le i\le 4$, the $"i"$ indexed box must at least have $i$ balls and at max $10i$ balls.

Comment: Have you heard of stars and bars?  How about inclusion-exclusion?  This should follow directly from both of those concepts.

Comment: Nope never heard of it.

Comment: Worth remarking that the cap condition isn't all that onerous.  Box $4$ couldn't contain $40$ balls anyway, and there's only one way box $3$ could hold $30$ (and that way is excluded by the other constraint), so the constraint only has force for $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

$$[x^{30}]: (x+\dots+x^{10})(x^2+\dots+x^{20})(x^3+\dots+x^{30})(x^4+\dots+x^{40})$$

where $[x^{30}]:$ is the coefficient of $x^{30}$, and each term represents the ways to put balls into the $i^{th}$ box.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider brackets corresponding to each box. 
$$(x^1+x^2+\dots+x^{10})\;\dots\text{(for $1$)}\\
(x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{20}) \;\dots\text{(for $2$)}\\
(x^3+x^4+\dots+x^{30})\;\dots\text{(for $3$)} \\
(x^4+x^5+\dots+x^{40})\;\dots\text{(for $4$)} $$

Here, the powers of $x$ represents the no. of balls the box can receive. There is no significance of $x$ but we are interested in powers of $x$. Now, the total no. of distributions is coefficient of $x^{30}$ in 
$(x^1+x^2+\dots+x^{10})(x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{20})(x^3+x^4+\dots+x^{30})(x^4+x^5+\dots+x^{40}) $

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to read up on [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to understand this answer.

The lower bounds are straightforward to deal with: Put $i$ balls in box $i$ and then distribute the remaining $30-\sum_{i=1}^4i=20$ balls over the $4$ boxes, with box $i$ receiving at most $9i$ more balls.

As @lulu remarked, only the first two upper bounds are actually constraints. There are $\binom{20+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{23}3$ ways to distribute the $20$ balls over $4$ boxes without constraints, $\binom{20-10+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{13}3$ ways to first put $10$ more balls into box $1$ to violate the first constraint and then distribute the remaining $20-10$ balls over $4$ boxes, and $\binom{20-19+4-1}{4-1}=\binom43$ ways to first put $19$ more balls into box $2$ to violate the second constraint and then distribute the remaining $20-19$ balls over $4$ boxes. Usually we would now have to deal with the cases where both constraints are violated using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), but here it’s impossible to violate both constraints. So we’re done, and the total is

$$
\binom{23}3-\binom{13}3-\binom43=1481\;.
$$